# Bootstrap table - right column is dropped from DIV parent

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I used the following code for bootstrap table. I am using Bootstrap V4.

No features are manually added to the tags.

```
<div class="fd-user-item-cart">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th scope="col">111111111</th>
               <th scope="col">222222222</th>
               <th scope="col">333333333</th>
               <th scope="col">444444444</th>
               <th scope="col">555555555</th>
               <th scope="col">666666666</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>1396/02/08</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>#456532</td>
               <td><img src="images/food-mini.jpg" alt=""></td>
               <td>asdasdasd</td>
               <td>1</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

But, there is a problem with responsive

[image: Image number one]

In the tablet's display mode, the right column is dropped from DIV parent. No features are manually added to the tags.

Comment: What is the issue ? Are the columns going beyond max-width ?

Comment: Thanks.In the tablet's display mode, the right column is dropped from DIV parent . No features are manually added to the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the official documentation of bootstrap 4 [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/#responsive-tables).

```
<table class="table table-responsive"> <!--Add more classes for styling if needed-->
  <thead>
  . . .
</table>
```

The `.table` and `.table-responsive` are the most important ones. Use them and it will be responsive.

Comment: Also you dont need `.col-md-6` or any `.col` when you are using a responsive table class. Dont use them actually..

Answer (score 0):

Change your first line to

```
<div class="table-responsive">
```

Comment: You also need the `table` class?

Comment: Isnt table class supposed to be on the *table* and not on the `<div>`? That is the official docs says?

Comment: Please read [this](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/#responsive-tables). He is using bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

use this instead of ur code.

```
<div class="fd-user-item-cart table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th scope="col">111111111</th>
           <th scope="col">222222222</th>
           <th scope="col">333333333</th>
           <th scope="col">444444444</th>
           <th scope="col">555555555</th>
           <th scope="col">666666666</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>1396/02/08</td>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>#456532</td>
           <td><img src="images/food-mini.jpg" alt=""></td>
           <td>asdasdasd</td>
           <td>1</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your 1st line.
Edit that and hopefully  it will work for you.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
```